# Change system clock by ProcessLauncher on uwp

Tags: c#, powershell, raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, impersonation

I'm trying to run a powershell script on raspberry (uwp) to change the system clock by c#.

Running the code below throw an exception 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'.

```
await ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync(..."set-date.ps1", date.ToString());
```

set-date.ps1 file content:

```
function Set-Time ([string]$dateTime) {
    $newDate = Get-Date $dateTime
    Set-Date $newDate 
}
```

I'm trying to find other way to do it or try to run ProcessLauncher inside impersonator, but i don't know how to do it on uwp.

> According Microsoft: "Note, ProcessLauncher API launches executables under the current user credentials, or DefautlAccount, so apps requiring admin priviliges will fail to run properly."

Any help to change system clock?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm having the same error come up when running the https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/ExternalProcessLauncher/CS solution.

Answer (score 1):

You must be Add application with below code to add those in **AllowedExecutableFilesList** registry in windows Iot core , so you need use below command to add applications or files to AllowedExecutableFilesList Key in windows registry:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\EmbeddedMode\ProcessLauncher" /v AllowedExecutableFilesList /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "c:\windows\system32\ipconfig.exe"\0"c:\windows\system32\tlist.exe"\0"c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe\0"
```

Go ahead, run the command above on your device, using [SSH](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/SSH.htm) or [PowerShell](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm). after that you authorize to access this apps and files.

> **Note** : `ProcessLauncher` API launches executables under the current user credentials, or DefautlAccount, so apps requiring admin priviliges will fail to run properly.

see this link for more details :

https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/ProcessLauncherSample.htm

Comment: That link has changed to: https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/ExternalProcessLauncher/CS

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, out of the box, for security questions.